# How to search by context using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I'm having trouble understanding how the "tagged_with" method would work in the case where I wanted to search "by context".

For example, if I have the following @user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
    end

@user1 = User.new(:name => "Bobby")
@user1.interest_list = "1, 2"     
@user1.skill_list = "5, 3, 4"
@user1.save

@user2 = User.new(:name => "Al")
@user2.interest_list = "2, 4"     
@user2.skill_list = "1, 3, 4"
@user2.save
```

I know that

```
User.tagged_with(["1"], :any => true)
```

will give me back both @user1 and @user2, b/c it doesn't distinguish between interest"1" tag or skill"1" tag. 
But my question is: Is there a way to search for Users with tag "1" in "interests" context only and *not* "skills" context ? In other words, how do i fetch just @user2 by specifying "skill" "1" somehow ?

Thanks for you help, guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `on` option:

```
User.tagged_with(["1"], :on => :skills)
```

See the section entitled "Dynamic Tag Contexts" at [the readme](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#readme) and [this cheat sheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/acts_as_taggable_on/) for a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your really quick reply. It works ! And thanks for the awesome cheatsheet, man! Ok, it's been only 3 mins so I'll wait for another 5 to click "accept answer" :)

Comment: Glad to help! Note that those cheat sheets work on the command line too. `gem install cheat` ^_^

Comment: Hi Brandon, I created a follow-up question to this here, would you mind having a look for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539583/does-the-any-flag-overwrites-the-on-context-flag-in-acts-as-taggable-ons-tag