# Does the :any flag overwrites the :on (context) flag in acts_as_taggable_on's tagged_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I'm confused with how the flags :on and :any works together in the "tagged_with" method of acts_as_taggable_on.

For example, if I have the following users @user1 and @user2:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
    end

@user1 = User.new(:name => "Bobby")
@user1.interest_list = "1, 15"     
@user1.skill_list = "2, 17"
@user1.save

@user2 = User.new(:name => "Al")
@user2.interest_list = "3, 10"     
@user2.skill_list = "4, 6"
@user2.save
```

When I want to get all users who's interest-list include any of the tag ["2", "50"], i tried this:

```
User.tagged_with(["2", "50"], :on => :interests, :any => true)
```

The problem is I get back @user1 (which has "2" in the skill_list, not interest_list), even though I was expecting none. It seems that the flag :any might have overwritten the flag :on. Is there a way to actually perform the filter I described above?

Also, a side question is, how do you find all the flags available to a method? For example, tagged_with has :on, :any, :match_all, ..., how do i list all of them ?

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: I'm no expert in acts-as-taggable-on, but I glanced through the source code and [it appears that it should be working as expected](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/2752cfe/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb#L91). What is the SQL query that's generated when you execute this code?

Comment: Yea I found it weird as well, the source code indeed includes the right logic for the flags. The problem is that the method tagged_with had a major fix checked in on March 18 2011, and it's not yet part of the gem on rubygem.org yet. After referencing straight from :git, everything works as the source says now. Thanks, Brandon, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found the where the problem is. Thanks to aurelian for pointing me to the source of acts_as_taggable_on. 
It turned out that the fix for :any overwriting :on issue was fixed as of March 18 on github master. And the gem from rubygem.org doesn't include this fix yet.

So instead of building my app from rubygem.org using: 
`gem 'acts_as_taggable_on'`

I just point it straight to the git source:
 `gem 'acts_as_taggable_on', :git => 'git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git'`

Answer (score 1):

> how do you find all the flags available to a method?

Try to develop your "source code reading" skills. A good 3rd party library will always document the available options for [the key methods that it expose](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb#L58).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the source code. Beside all the flags, I did find the answer to my original question about the flags.